# Is it possible to apply an angular material theme and custom material component theme?

Tags: angular, sass, scss-mixins

Im trying to maintain a global angular material theme whilst also targeting a specific material component and applying a custom theme onto it.

My approach is to firstly apply the global angular material theme using:

```
@include angular-material-theme($theme);
```

This applies my theme to all angular material components.

Then, I want to target for example the mat-form-field component and apply a custom theme onto it, essentially overriding the global theme for this specific component:

```
@include mat.form-field-theme($custom-formfield-theme);
```

Currently this approach does not work, the global theme is still present on the mat-form-field.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this, or if its even possible ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your app workspace create `src/custom-mat-theme.scss`, for example:

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@include mat.core();
$my-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$amber-palette, 300);
$my-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$amber-palette, A200, A100, A400);
$my-warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);

$my-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $my-primary,
    accent: $my-accent,
    warn: $my-warn,
  ),
  typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
  density: 0,
),
);
@include mat.form-field-color($my-theme);
```

Point in `angular.json` configuration file to your custom theme file. Also make sure to reference a pre-built theme CSS file with a different color palette to ensure that your custom theme is applied correctly:

```
       ...
        "styles": [
          "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
          "src/styles.css",
          "src/custom-mat-theme.scss"
        ],...
```

This should display `my-theme` color definitions for `form-fields`, while the rest of your components use the pre-built theme. For multiple themes, see also [here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#multiple-themes-in-one-file).